# Using PasswordEncoder from Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I want use the PasswordEnconder from Spring Security in my application, but almost all documentation and blogs I found in Google teach this procedure with the use of .userDetailsService() in method configureGlobal in SecurityConfig class.

In my application, I have a custom AuthenticationProvider, which made use of a AuthenticationService (listed below). Anyone can point a direction of how modify my code to include support for this resource?

**SecurityConfig**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(value="com.spring.webapp.lojavirtual")
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
    }

    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf()
                .disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/erro/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/bootstrap/**", "/jquery/**", "/extra/**", "/publico/**", "/erro/publico/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/acesso/login").permitAll()
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login").permitAll()
                .usernameParameter("login")
                .passwordParameter("senha")
                .successHandler(new CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler())
                .failureHandler(new CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler())
                .and()
            .rememberMe()
                .key("lembrete")
                .useSecureCookie(true)
                .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/acesso/login").permitAll();
    }

}
```

**CustomAuthenticationProvider**

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationService usuario;

    public CustomAuthenticationProvider() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        String name = authentication.getName();
        String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

        UserDetails user = usuario.loadUserByUsername(name);

        if(user.getPassword().equals(password)) {
            Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), user.getAuthorities());
            return auth;
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
    }

}
```

**AuthenticationService**

```
@Service
public class AuthenticationService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UsuarioHome accountDao;

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true, propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS)
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Usuario account = accountDao.findByField("login", username);

        if(account==null) {
            System.out.println("No such user: " + username);
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("No such user: " + username);
        } else if (account.getAutorizacao().isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("User " + username + " has no authorities");
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User " + username + " has no authorities");
        }

        List<Permission> lista = new ArrayList<Permission>();
        int max = account.getAutorizacao().size();
        for(int i=0; i<max; i++) {
            for(int j=0; j<max; j++) {
                lista.add(account.getAutorizacao().get(i).getPermissao().get(j));
            }
        }

        boolean accountIsEnabled = true;
        boolean accountNonExpired = true;
        boolean credentialsNonExpired = true;
        boolean accountNonLocked = true;

        return new User(account.getLogin(), account.getSenha(), accountIsEnabled, accountNonExpired, credentialsNonExpired, accountNonLocked, getAuthorities(lista));
    }

    public List<String> getRolesAsList(List<Permission> list) {
        List <String> rolesAsList = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(Permission role : list){
            rolesAsList.add(role.getNome());
        }
        return rolesAsList;
    }

    public static List<GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities(List<String> roles) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
        for (String role : roles) {
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role));
        }
        return authorities;
    }

    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(List<Permission> list) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> authList = getGrantedAuthorities(getRolesAsList(list));
        return authList;
    }

}
```

Comment: Why the `CustomAuthenticationProvider`? The only thing you need is the custom `UserDetailsService` implementation, the remainder can be done with Spring Security!

Comment: In this moment, seems like I don't need the Custom AuthenticationProvider, but I will need in the future; because so, I am finding a solution where I can keep it.

Comment: If you don't need it don't build it... The best maintainable code is code not written! In general you mostly don't need a custom `AuthenticationProvider` but can implement some of the collaborating classes instead of doing everything yourself. BUt alas, your bean is just a bean like everyother bean, just create a property and have that injected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be simple. Replace this:

```
user.getPassword().equals(password)
```

with this

```
encoder.matches(password, user.getPassword())
```

Comment: Then I did this change in my CustomAuthenticationProvider and add the a class BCryptPasswordEncoder which implement PasswordEncoder (following the example shown in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13387148/spring-security-custom-passwordencoder-never-called-when-authenticating) and now I am facing the error **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid salt version** after I inform my credencials and try login in the system. Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Ok, then i get to solve this particular error, but i can't login in the system yet. Happens that, in my database, my password are encrypted with MD5, and i think the code don't encode the password to Md5. Am I right? If so, how correct that?